# XCode C++ Program not running proper loops

Tags: c++, xcode, if-statement, random, while-loop

I am having issues with my program and am looking for some help. My program is supposed to randomly choose who gets to go first, the user or the computer. The program does that just fine, when I input the weapon I want to use it does the proper calculations and subtracts the right amount of randomly generated damage from the computer's health and vice versa if the computer gets to go first. Whether it is the user or the computer going first, after you press enter the program just stops. It is supposed to keep going until either the user or the computer's health reaches zero. I was wondering if I could get some assistance as to where my code is preventing this from happening. Any help would be appreciated, I am a novice with the C++ language. Thank you!

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()  // Setting the "stage" for the code to follow.
{
    int Player_Health = 100; // Creating the necessary variables for the program.
    int Comp_Health = 100;
    int Turn;
    int Weapon_Selection;
    int Comp_Weapon;
    int Cannon_Dmg;
    int Grenade_Dmg;
    int Rifle_Dmg;
    int Player_Cannon_Ammo = 3;
    int Player_Grenade_Ammo = 4;
    int Comp_Cannon_Ammo = 3;
    int Comp_Grenade_Ammo = 4;

    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));

    Turn = rand() % 2; // Randomizing who gets to go first.

    while(Player_Health >= 0 && Comp_Health >= 0)
    {
        if(Turn == 0)  // Player gets to go first.
        {
            cout << "You get to go first!\n";
            cout << "Select a weapon using number keys 1, 2, or 3.\n";
            cout << "1. Cannon\n";
            cout << "2. Grenade\n";
            cout << "3. Rifle\n";
            cout << "\n";
            cout << "You select: ";
            cin >> Weapon_Selection;

            while((Weapon_Selection < 1 || Weapon_Selection > 3) || (Weapon_Selection == 1 && Player_Cannon_Ammo == 0)
                  || (Weapon_Selection == 2 && Player_Grenade_Ammo == 0))
            {
                cout << "Please enter a valid option.\n";
                cout << "You select: ";
                cin >> Weapon_Selection;
            }

            switch(Weapon_Selection)
            {
                case 1: // Player chooses to shoot the cannon.
                    Cannon_Dmg = 10 + rand() % 6;
                    Comp_Health = Comp_Health - Cannon_Dmg;
                    cout << "You caused " << Cannon_Dmg << " damage to your enemy.\n";
                    cout << "Your health is " << Player_Health << endl;
                    cout <<" The computer's health is " << Comp_Health << endl;
                    Player_Cannon_Ammo = Player_Cannon_Ammo - 1;
                    break;

                case 2: // Player chooses to lob a grenade.
                    Grenade_Dmg = 7 + rand() % 6;
                    Comp_Health = Comp_Health - Grenade_Dmg;
                    cout << "You caused " << Grenade_Dmg << " damage to your enemy.\n";
                    cout << "Your health is " << Player_Health << endl;
                    cout << "The computer's health is " << Comp_Health << endl;
                    Player_Grenade_Ammo = Player_Grenade_Ammo - 1;
                    break;

                case 3: // Player chooses to shoot the rifle.
                    Rifle_Dmg = 3 + rand() % 6;
                    Comp_Health = Comp_Health - Rifle_Dmg;
                    cout << "You caused " << Rifle_Dmg << " damage to your enemy.\n";
                    cout << "Your health is " << Player_Health << endl;
                    cout << "The computer's health is " << Comp_Health << endl;
                    break;


            }


        }

        else // Computer gets to go first.
        {
            Comp_Weapon = rand() % 3;

            switch(Comp_Weapon)  // Computer randomly selects a weapon.
            {
                case 1:
                    Cannon_Dmg = 10 + rand() % 6;
                    Player_Health = Player_Health - Cannon_Dmg;
                    cout << "Your enemy used a cannon and caused " << Cannon_Dmg << " damage to you.\n";
                    cout << "Your health is " << Player_Health << endl;
                    cout << "The computer's health is " << Comp_Health << endl;
                    Comp_Cannon_Ammo = Comp_Cannon_Ammo - 1;
                    break;

                case 2:
                    Grenade_Dmg = 7 + rand() % 6;
                    Player_Health = Player_Health - Grenade_Dmg;
                    cout << "Your enemy used a grenade and caused " << Grenade_Dmg << " damage to you.\n";
                    cout << "Your health is " << Player_Health << endl;
                    cout << "The computer's health is " << Comp_Health << endl;
                    Comp_Grenade_Ammo = Comp_Grenade_Ammo - 1;
                    break;

                case 3:
                    Rifle_Dmg = 3 + rand() % 6;
                    Player_Health = Player_Health - Rifle_Dmg;
                    cout << "Your enemy used a rifle and caused " << Rifle_Dmg << " damage to you.\n";
                    cout << "Your health is " << Player_Health << endl;
                    cout << "The computer's health is " << Comp_Health << endl;
                    break;




            }


        }


        if (Comp_Health < 0)
            cout << "Congratulations, you beat your enemy!" << endl;

        if (Player_Health < 0)
            cout << "You have been defeated by your enemy!" << endl;;



        cin.ignore(2);
        return 0;

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try using a debugger?

Comment: There are no errors. Its something to do with the positions of the loops.

Comment: But, the behavior of your code differs, from your expectations? Debugger is THE tool to use, in such circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like several issues.

How does Turn get changed from it initial value?  Looks like whoever goes first will go until the other player is out of health

rand%3 will return 0,1 or 2.  The switch is for 1,2,3.  The 0 case is ignored.

The return statement is inside the while loop and the program hangs on the cin.ignore(2) line

I fixed these issue up and the program appears to be more or less working.

--Matt

Comment: So i moved the return statement out of the while loop and the program continues but you're right, it picked me to go first but then after I selected it ran the same code I get when I am randomly picked first. How can I fix this?

Comment: I just set Turn =1 in the top section and Turn  = 0 in the bottom section.  This alternates turns.  The comment about going first should probably be moved outside of the loop

Comment: As in if the player goes first you put in "Turn == 1"? Not sure what defines the top section and what defines the bottom section :D. I removed the output about going first. Also, for the computer to randomly select a weapon, What should I make the random statement be so that only 1, 2, or 3 can be selected as opposed to the 0, 1, and 2?

Comment: Just add one to the output of the rand, value = (rand()%3)+1

Comment: if(Turn == 0)  // Player gets to go first.
        {
            Turn = 1;
...
       else // Computer gets to go first.
        {
            Turn = 0;

Comment: Im confsed by the above statement, so I keep Turn == 0 and then after the first bracket I write in Turn = 1? And then under else after the first bracket I write in Turn = 0? Sorry for all the questions, like I said im very new to this stuff.

Comment: By alternating the value of Turn, the loop will enter both players sections.  So if the computer goes first (Turn==1) then on the next pass the player will go and so on

Comment: I cannot write "Turn == 1" by itself under my else statement (the else is what allows the computer to go first since "Turn == 0" means the player goes first.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `return` statement outside of the `while` loop.

Using a debugger would catch this.

Comment: How do I use the debugger in XCode? I moved the return statement out but if I am randomly selected first and I choose my weapon it gives me the same code I get when I get randomly picked to go first again.